# Setting properties of Button

Tags: android

How to set Button  **"Layout below"**  properties by **code** in android inside an **Relativelayout**
i have defined relative layout by using findviewby id.

Answer (score 1):

use addRule() of LayoutParams to set layout below

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lineParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        lineParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, myview.getId());
```

Add this button to RelativeLayout which is defined

```
Relativelayout rl= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Relativelayout01);
rl.addView(b,lineParams);
```

Comment: I want to add button inside the relative layout which i has already defined by Relativelayout rl= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Relativelayout01); and i want to add button as a child in Relativelayout01

Comment: I want to add  button inside the relative layout which i have already defined by Relativelayout rl= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Relativelayout);

Comment: see my answer now. i have edited my answer as per your requirement

Comment: rl= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Relativelayout);           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lineParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        lineParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 123);
        rl.addView(b1,lineParams);  "I m getting an error [the specified child already has parent] "

Comment: first remove all views from that layout rl= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Relativelayout); rl.removeAllViews();  then do your tasks